# Как учесть все запросы к файлам (*.gif) c сайта

Tags: .htaccess, php, mysql

Есть сайт, на нем хранится много-много анимаций. Хочется посмотреть, как часто обращаются по адресу: `site.ru/gifs/some_name_of_gif_file.gif`.
Понимаю, что нужно редиректить все запросы к папке *gifs* на какой-нибудь *php* файл, там сохранять информацию о запросе к картинке и затем отдавать сам файл. Но как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Файл .htaccess

```
#if
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(gif|GIF)
#then
RewriteRule ^.* gif.php [L]
```

Далее в файле gif.php ставим счетчик, и выводим саму картинку.